# Foreach Loop Dynamic Creation of TabPages, and Labels

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, foreach

In regards to the foreach loop that I have created below I have a concern about the creation of the accessibility of the items. As I am looping over an a tabpage being instantiated does the program distinctly know the differences in each page it is creating and if so how could I access it?

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.Data;

namespace assignment_manager_source
{
    partial class HomeworkAgenda
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///  Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;
        private TabControl tabCtrl1;
        private TabPage landingPage;
        private TabPage dynamoPage;
        private Label dynamoLabel;
        private Label nxtpage0;
        public string conn = @"Data Source="+ Application.StartupPath +"\\classes.db";


        /// <summary>
        ///  Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        ///  Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        ///  the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager resources = new System.ComponentModel.ComponentResourceManager();
            // Tab Controls

            this.tabCtrl1 = new TabControl
            {
                Alignment = TabAlignment.Left,
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed,
                ItemSize = new Size(50, 100),
                Location = new Point(0, 0),
                Multiline = true,
                Name = "Landing Page",
                SelectedIndex = 0,
                Size = new Size(448, 448),
                SizeMode = TabSizeMode.Fixed,
                TabIndex = 0,
            };
            //Labels


            this.nxtpage0 = new Label
            {
                AutoSize = true,
                Font = new Font("Calibri", 12.6F, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point),
                Location = new Point(Bottom, Right),
                Name = "Classes",
                Text = "Next >",
                Visible = true
            };
            this.nxtpage0.Visible = true;

            // Pages

            this.landingPage = new TabPage
            {
                Controls =
                {
                    this.nxtpage0
                },
                Location = new Point(20, 20),
                Name = "Assignment Manager",
                Padding = new Padding(3),
                Size = new Size(224,224),
                TabIndex = 0,
                Text = "View Assignments",
                UseVisualStyleBackColor = true
            };
            this.landingPage.SuspendLayout();
            this.tabCtrl1.Controls.Add(this.landingPage);
            // Labels
            var connection = new SQLiteConnection(conn);
            connection.Open();

            var sql_query = "SELECT cname FROM classes;";
            var command = new SQLiteCommand(sql_query, connection);

            var dt_1 = new DataTable();
            var dt_2 = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                dt_1.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("Box 0");
                connection.Close();
            }

            var combobox = new ComboBox();

            foreach (DataRow row in dt_1.Rows)
            {
                
                combobox.Items.Add(row["cname"].ToString());
                combobox.AutoSize= true;
               

                
            }
            combobox.SelectedIndexChanged += class_name_SelectedIndexChanged;
            this.landingPage.Controls.Add(combobox);
            sql_query = "SELECT cid FROM classes";
            command = new SQLiteCommand(sql_query, connection);
            dt_1 = new DataTable();
            try
            {
                dt_1.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
            }
            catch (SQLiteException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show("Box 1");
                connection.Close();
            }
            foreach (DataRow row in dt_1.Rows)
            {
                this.dynamoPage = new TabPage();
                string name = row["cid"].ToString();
                this.dynamoPage.Text = name;
                sql_query = "SELECT classes.cid, hw_name FROM classes" +
                " INNER JOIN assignments ON classes.cid = assignments.cid" +
                " WHERE classes.cid= \'" + name+"\'";
                command = new SQLiteCommand(sql_query, connection);
                try
                {
                    dt_2.Load(command.ExecuteReader());
                }
                catch (SQLiteException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    connection.Close();
                }
                foreach (DataRow row1 in dt_2.Rows)
                {
                    if (row1["cid"].ToString() == name)
                    {
                        this.dynamoLabel = new Label();
                        string name1 = row1["hw_name"].ToString();
                        this.dynamoLabel.Text = name1;
                        this.dynamoPage.Controls.Add(this.dynamoLabel);
                    }
                    
                }
                this.tabCtrl1.Controls.Add(this.dynamoPage);


            }
            
                //}
                //foreach (DataRow row in dt_1.Rows)
                //{
                //    var dyanmo_page = new Label();
                //}

            connection.Close();


            
            this.tabCtrl1.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(this.tbctrl);
            this.tabCtrl1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(this.tabCtrl1_SIC);

            this.Controls.Add(this.tabCtrl1);
            this.tabCtrl1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.landingPage.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.landingPage.PerformLayout();
        }



        #endregion
    }
}
```

The variable that concerns me is DynamoPage. There are multiple copies of DynamoPage each with looping over leading to doubts that I will be even able to access one of the copies with a specific class name. Is there a property or method I could use to distinguish the various "copies".

Comment: You can access them via `this.tabCtrl1.Controls` in this class or accessing instance of this class and using its `tabCtrl1` property if you are exposing it.